# how mock requests.get.return_value with different values in python

Tags: python, pytest

I am writing a test case with pytest to test a rest api call to get a token. The token will be expired in 15 minutes. I am testing the api will be called twice with different tokens when expired. Following is my test method:

```
@patch("package.api.requests.get")
def test_get_access_token_expired(mocked_requests_get):
    mocked_requests_get.return_value.text = "".join(
        secrets.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(7)
    )
    client = MyClient("", "", "", "")
    client._get_access_token()
    token1 = client._access_token
    client._token_expired_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=15)
    client._get_access_token()
    token2 = client._access_token
    print(f"token1: {token1}, token2: {token2}")
    assert token1 != token2
    assert mocked_requests_get.call_count == 2
```

The mocked requests did get called twice. But somehow the token1 and token2 are always the same. Not sure why? Can anyone tell me what I missed? Also, by the document, the target of the patch should be package.module.ClassName, but if I put my class name there like package.api.MyClient.requests.get, it gave me ModuleNotFoundError. Why?

Thanks for the response. I tried with side_effect like:

```
mocked_requests_get.side_effect=[
        Mock(**{"return_value": {"text": "abc"}}), Mock(**{"return_value": {"text": "123"}})
    ]
```

The token1 is different than token2. But how come the token1 is assigned like `<Mock name='mock.text' id='4485261536'>`? How could I make the token1 is "abc"?

Comment: Why would they be different? You only set one return value. Also why are you directly calling private (based on the conventional underscore prefix) methods directly?

Comment: Search how to use side_effect instead of return_value

Comment: also, there is requests-mock package exists, could be useful for more complex cases

Comment: See also [`responses`](https://pypi.org/project/responses/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`return_value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value) will always return the same fixed value.

> Set this to configure the value returned by calling the mock:

If you want a **function** to be called you should look at [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect):

> This can either be a function to be called when the mock is called, an iterable or an exception (class or instance) to be raised

#### Option 1: Changing the `return_value`

Just set the return value twice

```py
from mock import patch
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with patch("requests.get") as mocked_requests_get:
        mocked_requests_get.return_value.text = 1
        print(requests.get("nice").text)
        mocked_requests_get.return_value.text = 2
        print(requests.get("nice").text)

# output
# >> 1
# >> 2
```

#### Option 2: Using `side_effect`

`side_effect` is a bit trickier, in that you can't immediately specify an attribute to apply to (at least to my knowledge).

It may be easier/clearer to return an iterable of mock response objects like:

```py
from mock import patch, MagicMock
from random import randint
import requests


def some_random_key(*args, **kwargs):
    return "".join([str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(7)])


class MockRequestResponse(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with patch("requests.get") as mocked_requests_get:
        mocked_requests_get.side_effect = [
            MockRequestResponse(text=some_random_key()) for _ in range(2)
        ]
        print(requests.get("nice").text)
        print(requests.get("nice").text)

# output
# >> 9604410
# >> 2126280
```

If you do find yourself using needing more of the features/attributes of the Response object, rather than making your own mock response object, you may want to consider [`requests-mock`'s Response Lists](https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/response.html#response-lists) as suggested in the comments.

#### Where to patch

My general guidance would be to patch what you can import from another file. e.g. you cannot patch `package.api.MyClient.requests.get` as you wouldn't be able to import requests from your MyClient class. The `package.module.ClassName` in documentations is therefore allowed as you can import a class from another file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried the second option, exactly what I want. Thanks again.